# $\frac{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdots p_k}{5}+1$

Tags: number-theory

Let be $n$ equal $$n=\frac{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdots p_k}{5}+1$$ for some $k$ where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime number.
Is it true that if $n$ is prime, then $n-p_k-1$ is either prime or a multiple of 5?

Can that be proven?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking ... what is $n$?  How does $n$ relate to that formula?

Comment: How many prime numbers are in the numerator? Why do you choose 5 as the denominator?

Comment: @user355705 Numbers in the numerator are 2*3*5*7*11*13*17...taken over all primes...

Comment: Why not cancel the 5 from the numerator? Also one can't take such products "over all primes".

Comment: If you take all primes the product will be infinite.

Comment: I think that yes, that the OP is interested in learn more mathematics, my intention was provide a code and tools with which work, and of course I am wrong sometimes with my posts. Always is required to do experiments before writting conjectures. Best wishes  @user355705

Comment: I add here this code written in Pari GP, this is a line `for (i = 1, 11, print(1+(1/5)*prod(k=1, i, prime(k))))` that I wrote after I read the examples given in the first answer. I write thus this comment as companion of the answers below. Everyone can run this code, or enrich it, in this [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/), choose *GP* as Language and after make Evaluate. In internet there are notes about this language and a reference card from the Université Bordeaux I.

Comment: @user243301 It is much simpler to run Wolfram Alpha but probably OP is not interested to check his discoveries before posting them here.

Comment: @EnzoCreti: How many times are you planning to change your question? Everytime user Henry comes us with a counter-example, you change your condtions.

Comment: If you change the conditions of the question, you  render our previous answers useless...

Comment: Quick answer to all these questions and the ones which could follow: No, you are not going to find a prime-generating formula of this kind

Comment: @Jose Brox I am absolutely sure that the questions will follow.

Comment: As a matter of fact your new "conjecture" fails already for $p_5=11$. $n_5-p_5-1=451=11\times41$.

Answer (score 6):

No

$\tfrac{2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 17 \times 19 \times 23 \times 29 \times 31 \times 37 \times 41 \times 43 \times 47 \times 53 \times 59 \times 61 \times 67 \times 71 \times 73 \times 79 \times 83}5 + 1 $ $= 53412903137855170271124803598559$ which is prime

but subtracting $2$

$\tfrac{2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 17 \times 19 \times 23 \times 29 \times 31 \times 37 \times 41 \times 43 \times 47 \times 53 \times 59 \times 61 \times 67 \times 71 \times 73 \times 79 \times 83}5 - 1 $ $= 53412903137855170271124803598557
 = 13399153 \times 9500816407 \times 419573365701467 $ which is not prime nor a multiple of $5$

Comment: No that is not an answer...I mean that 2*3*5...31/5 -1 is divisible by 5.

Comment: @EnzoCreti Why put $+1$ in the question title when you mean $-1$?

Comment: @Henry Probably it is intended to mislead the readers.

Comment: @kingW3 - try now

Comment: @Henry Nice. (+1)

Comment: @Henry: The OP changed his conditions again.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII - thank you for warning me.   I will stop here

Answer (score 2):

The number:

$$n_{75}=\tfrac{2\times 3\times 5\times \dots\times 379}5+1$$ is prime.

$n_{75}-2$ is neither prime nor divisible by $5$: $n_{75}\mod 5 =3 $.

Comment: But i guess that n75-380 is divisible by 5?

Comment: You could see it from my answer that the answer is "NO" as the value  $p_{75} \mod 5$ was given.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $n$ in your question is the result of your formula.

Denote $m\#:=2\times 3\times 5\times\ldots\times p_m$ (where $p_m$ is the $m$th prime). Then $m\#+1,m\#-1$ cannot be a multiple of any of the primes $2,\ldots,p_m$. So any prime dividing $m\#-1$ must be greater than $p_m$. If you divide by $5$, then any prime dividing $n-2=m\#/5-1$ must be either $5$ or greater than $p_m$. But $m\#/5-1$ does not need to be prime itself, nor a multiple of 5. For example, $$9\#/5-1=2\times 3\times 7\times\ldots\times 23-1=59\times 756247.$$